# Inserir NIB na base de dados

Tags: java

Qual o tipo de dados indicado para receber o NIB (Número de Identificação Bancária) numa base de dados?

O NIB é constituído por 21 dígitos.

Tenho tentado mas aparece o seguinte erro:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'NIB' at row 1
```

Comment: Coloque aí a estrutura da tabela em questão pra facilitar a compreensão da exceção.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O erro é devido ao facto de estares a utilizar um tipo numérico que não tem dimensão para conter esse número.
Além disso, apesar de o NIB ser constituído apenas por caracteres numéricos, este não pode ser representado por um tipo numérico porque pode ter dígitos 0 no inicio.

Assim terás de utilizar um tipo *string*.
Como o número de caracteres é constante e conhecido a escolha é `char(21)`.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento !